# Number guessing game: Different message when guess = >100?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm creating a little number guessing game for class and I have a question that my prof still hasn't spoken about:

In my if-statements I have different messages telling the player when the guess is < random number, > the random number and == the random number. Now I would like to also print a message when the guess is too far off the random number;

If the random number is 700 and my guess is more than 100 off, how do I put this in the if-statement? I have of course tried guess + >100 but that obviously doesn't work. Do I need a new variable for this?

Comment: Hi, Its hard to debug a story or read code in your head. Consider putting the code in the question so we have a better chance of helping

Comment: Show us some code you already have first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
if (Math.Abs(guessedNumber - randomNumber)> 100){
Console.WriteLine("Your number is so far from the random number")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either your guess will be 100 bigger or smaller then your number.

```
int randomNr = 350;
int guess =  250;
int maxOff = 100;

if (guess - randomNr > maxOff || randomNr - guess > maxOff)
{
    //Show message.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always try to include your code when asking a question.

Without having your code, this is a potential solution to your question :

**1. Print message telling by how much the guess is off**

```
int diff;
diff = random - guess;
if(diff > 0)
{

    Console.WriteLine($"guess is smaller by {diff}");

}

else if(diff < 0)
{

    Console.WriteLine($"Guess is greater by {diff}");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
  public static int rand = new Random().Next(0, 999);
  public static string myNumber; 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess the random number");
        do
        {
            myNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            IHopeIguessRandomNumber(Convert.ToInt32(myNumber));
        }
        while (Convert.ToInt32(myNumber) != rand);
    }



    public static void IHopeIguessRandomNumber(int myGuess)
    {
        if ( myGuess == rand)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You're right! This is the right number");
        }
        else if (myGuess <= rand - 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Too Low! Your number is < random");
        }
        else if ( myGuess < rand)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your number is < random");
        }
        else if (myGuess >= rand + 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Too Big! Your number is > random");
        }
        else if (myGuess > rand)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your number is > random");
        }
    }
```

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NESTED IF block like this.

```
if(guessNum < randomNum)
{
    if(guessNum < randomNum - 100)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("The guessed number is too Low");
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("The guessed number is Low, but you are close");
    }
}
else if(guessNum > randomNum)
{
    if(guessNum > randomNum + 100)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("The guessed number is too High");
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("The guessed number is High, but you are close");
    }
}
```

I can help you with the exact answer if you add the existing code snippet.